# How to change Map on Click Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a simple code below that will show a map in leaflet and here it is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0054)http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leafletjs.com/dist/leaflet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; position: relative;" class="leaflet-container leaflet-fade-anim" tabindex="0"><div class="leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="leaflet-tile-pane"><div class="leaflet-layer"><div class="leaflet-tile-container"></div><div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated"><img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: 56px; top: -91px;" src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/2723.png"><img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: 312px; top: -91px;" src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/2723(1).png"><img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: 56px; top: 165px;" src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/2724.png"><img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: 312px; top: 165px;" src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/2724(1).png"><img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: -200px; top: -91px;" src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/2723(2).png"><img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: 568px; top: -91px;" src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/2723(3).png"><img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: -200px; top: 165px;" src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/2724(2).png"><img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: 568px; top: 165px;" src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/2724(3).png"></div></div></div><div class="leaflet-objects-pane"><div class="leaflet-shadow-pane"><img src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/marker-shadow.png" class="leaflet-marker-shadow leaflet-zoom-animated" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 41px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(300px, 247px, 0px);"></div><div class="leaflet-overlay-pane"><svg class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="1172" height="781" viewBox="-286 -191 1172 781" style="transform: translate3d(-286px, -191px, 0px);"><g><path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" fill="#f03" fill-opacity="0.5" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M183,130A42,42,0,1,1,182.9,130 z"></path></g><g><path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#0033ff" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" fill="#0033ff" fill-opacity="0.2" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M358 163L474 219L550 153z"></path></g></svg></div><div class="leaflet-marker-pane"><img src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/marker-icon.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-clickable" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 25px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(300px, 247px, 0px); z-index: 247;"></div><div class="leaflet-popup-pane"><div class="leaflet-popup  leaflet-zoom-animated" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(300px, 247px, 0px); bottom: 27px; left: -56px;"><a class="leaflet-popup-close-button" href="http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html#close">×</a><div class="leaflet-popup-content-wrapper"><div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 74px;"><b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.</div></div><div class="leaflet-popup-tip-container"><div class="leaflet-popup-tip"></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="leaflet-control-container"><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"><div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html#" title="Zoom in">+</a><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out" href="http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html#" title="Zoom out">-</a></div></div><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right"><div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"><a href="http://leafletjs.com/" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a> | Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a></div></div></div></div>

    <script src="./Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example_files/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>

        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
        }).addTo(map);




    </script>


</body></html>
```

i just wanna ask how can i transfer or change the map view when i clicked on link button

```
Ex.
If i click Afghanistan
<button type="button">View Map of Afghanistan</button>
If i click iraq
<button type="button">View Map of Iraq</button>
```

and i hope the site will not refresh just only the map will change. any help is appreciated TY

Answer (score 2):

you need to put the correct id of the map (go to mapbox and get it from one of their examples or create an account and style one of your own ) . 
the only html markup you need for your div to work is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0054)http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leafletjs.com/dist/leaflet.css">
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
     #map { height: 480px; }
     
   </style>
   
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
    
    
<script type="text/javascript">
      var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-i86nkdio/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
        }).addTo(map);
      var gotocountry = function(c){
        // you get  afghanistan coordinates from google 
         if(c=='af')
         map.setView(new L.LatLng(34.5333, 69.1333), 6);
         if(c=='tn')
         map.setView(new L.LatLng(34,9), 6);
        return;
        
        
      };
     
   </script>
       

<br/>
<a onclick="gotocountry('af')"> Afghanistan</a>
<a onclick="gotocountry('tn')"> Tunisia</a>

</body></html>
```

[here is a working  example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IoMqN90fFOgFWZ9W1upN?p=info)